# Does Firefox has similar remote debugging protocol like Chrome Debugging Protocol

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, firefox, websocket

Chrome Debugging Protocol is a very good protocol to develop on Chrome, I am looking for the similar remote debugging protocol if Firefox support.

As I known, Firebug is the debugging tool of Firefox, but it is run as a plugin/extension, I need to debug Firefox with separated client connect to Firefox using websocket or other protocols, Then do some statistics for networking and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please see: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/remote/index.html.

It does support a subset of the chrome devtools protocol.

AFAIK, if you're trying to drive a browser like you can chrome, it will not work.